# Renderizar tamanho de imagem em celula de tabela

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Criei uma tabela em java que mostra as minhas imagens guardadas em blob na base de dados. No entanto a altura da tabela não fica automaticamente redimensionada tendo que colocar um valor manualmente, por exemplo:

```
Tabela.setRowHeight(60);
```

Eu gostava de obter o tamanho da imagem da base de dados guardada numa variável ImageIcon para todas as células com imagens serem automaticamente redimensionadas.

```
modelo.addRow(new Object[]{numero, icon});
```

A minha tabela fica assim sabendo que o predefini para a altura ser de 60:

[image: Imagem da tabela]

Sendo outra das opções renderizar o tamanho da imagem guardada na variável ImageIcon antes de a colocar na tabela, esta seria uma boa ideia?
Eu declaro a minha imagem assim:

```
Blob blob = produto.getBlob("imagem");
ImageIcon icon = null;
try (InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
      icon = new ImageIcon(img);
}
```

A minha tabela é criada assim:

```
private DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Name", "Image"}, 0) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnIndex == 1 ? Icon.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        };
```

Para inserir a imagem na tabela uso um botão com o seguinte código para a selecionar:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    d = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
    n = chooser.getName(f);
    if(n!=null){
        jLabel14.setText(n);
    }else{
        jLabel14.setText("Nenhuma imagem selecionada.");
    }
```

Após seleccionar o ficheiro clico num botão para correr uma query que a insere na base de dados:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);   
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into produtos (Nome,ID_Tipo_produto,Descricao,Preco,Data,Codigo,Referencia,Observacoes,Stock,Imagem) values ('" + txt_nome1.getText() + "','" + dados + "','" + txt_descricao.getText() + "','" + txt_preço1.getText() + "','" + txt_data.getText() + "','" + txt_codigo.getText() + "','" + txt_referencia.getText() + "','" + Observações.getText() + "','" + txt_stock.getText() + "',?)"); 
ps.setBinaryStream(1,fis,(int)f.length());
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
fis.close();
con.close();
```

Comment: Nem precisa armazenar, ao carregar uma imagem, tem como recuperar seu tamanho em tempo de execução. Adicione como você constroi sua tabela(se usa tablemodel, renderers, etc) para vermos qual o melhor jeito de resolver.

Comment: @diegofm Feito tem ai o meu método de inserir a imagem na base de dados e como construo a tabela, eu gostava de continuar a poder inserir na base de dados a imagem no fromato blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode reescrever o renderer da sua tabela, de forma que toda vez que ele identifique o tipo de dado `ImageIcon` em alguma célula, ele defina a altura somente daquela linha para a mesma da imagem:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (value instanceof ImageIcon) {
            ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) value;
            table.setRowHeight(row, icon.getIconHeight());
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
});
```

Neste caso, utilizei o método [`setRowHeight()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowHeight-int-int-) passando como parâmetro qual linha será alterada e a altura que deverá ser, sendo esta relativa ao tamanho da imagem daquela célula em particular.

Obs.: Antes de implementar a sugestão acima, recomendo que altere seu model para o abaixo:

```
private DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Name", "Image"}, 0) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 1 ? ImageIcon.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }
};
```